# Every redirection goes to localhost root for no reason

Tags: javascript, redirect, xampp

I have some login system which works/worked fine, after few logins page started to redirect to the localhost root page with xampp.

I tried restarting PC or using torch or chrome web browsers... Although it does that only on redirection if I go to those pages by url bar it works perfect.

I am login in by ajax request and that way I alert output where to redirect from php file.

```
alert(window.location+''+success);
window.location = window.location+''+success;
```

Where alert message says as on this [image: <code>pic</code>]:

In the `.htaccess` file that I had I had these code as comments since it did not work for me, yesterday I posted question for it and no one answered. So I left it as comment but since this started happening I deleted file from localhost folders.

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
#RewriteEngine on 
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} u=([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)  
#RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ %1? [R=301,L]   
#RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ ?marker&u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: is the redirection done by `js` or `php`. share snippet

Comment: As I said on js, I mentioned by ajax I am handling login and by success message I redirect to the page.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is.  Should the value of `window.location+''+success` *not* be what you're showing?  Why not?

Comment: It is the value of that but when it redirect to that value it not even get there i go straight to localhost root bcs on that location there is nothing that would redirect back by js or php

Comment: Slow down, and explain clearly: Does the javascript redirect to the full, proper URL? And once the page loads, it redirects to root? Or, does the js redirect directly to "root"? What happens if you copy that url to your clipboard, and past it into the browser - does it load properly?  Do you have any .htaccess file(s) in place that could be causing redirects?

Comment: @cale_b It does not redirect to full url it go straight to root, when i copy and paste it works normal without any redirection's to root. I had htaccess file and I removed it "deleted" from localhost folders just to make sure if that makes redirection but it still happens..

Comment: @cale_b I added update with htaccess code that I had.